# Создаю форму с помощью ModelForms и пишет что django forms не и меет атрибута ModelForm

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from .models import CommentModel

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = ('WhoAreYou', 'comment')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CommentModel(models.Model):
    WhoAreYou = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Покажите как импортируете `ModelForms` в файле forms.py.

Comment: from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from .models import CommentModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, CharField


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    comment = CharField()
```

Или так:

```
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: 2 вариант сработал спасибо !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
```

Думаю, что вот так должен выглядеть ваш класс.

Comment: Теперь пишет что не имеет атрибута Charfield :D

Comment: comment =CharField() тоже исправить